# Increment and decrement in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, increment, decrement

I am displaying a product in recyclerView. I  have 2 buttons + to symbolise increment and - to symbolise decrement. Once  the user adds product if he clicks + product quantity should increase and if - product quantity should decrease. Also by default product quantity should be set to 1 and product quantity should not be less than 0. But whenever I add new product previous quantity is getting set to 1 again. How to avoid that? Also how can the product_value be multiplied by quantity?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RVOrderBrdAdapter.RVViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //getting the product of the specified position
    OrderBrdDataModel product = filteredList.get(position);

    //binding the data with the viewholder views
    holder.brd_value.setText(product.getBrdprice());
    holder.brd_product.setText(product.getBrdname());
    holder.brd_quantity.setText("1");

    holder.brd_increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(holder.brd_quantity.getText().toString());
            number++;

            holder.brd_quantity.setText(""+number);
           
        }
    });

    holder.brd_decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(holder.brd_quantity.getText().toString());
            if(number<=0){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Quantity cannot be less than 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                number = 0;
            }else {
                number--;
                holder.brd_quantity.setText(""+number);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filteredList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return itemFilter;
}

public class RVViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView brd_value, brd_product,brd_quantity,brd_increment,brd_decrement;

    public RVViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        brd_value = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_value);
        brd_product = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_product);
        brd_quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_quantity);
        brd_increment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_increment);
        brd_decrement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_decrement);

    }

}
public class ItemFilter extends Filter{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
         ArrayList<OrderBrdDataModel> temp_filteredList= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<ordList.size();i++){
            if (ordList.get(i).isSelected()){
                temp_filteredList.add(ordList.get(i));
            }

        }
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = temp_filteredList;
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredList = (ArrayList)results.values;
        System.out.println("RvFilter " + filteredList.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

[image: image shows xml]

Answer (score 0):

In your increment or decrement click event, add or remove item from filteredList.

Then notify for your adapter with

```
yourAdapter.notifyItemChanged(positionCLick)
```